# jQuery triggers keyup event only if it was attached with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, onkeyup

Realy messed up with triggering `keyup` event using jQuery.

Here is the clean example

http://jsfiddle.net/xQcGM/2/

When I type in any of `input`'s, they both fire event, but when I try to fire it programmatically (`$(element).trigger('event')`) only the second one is triggered, but I expect both.

Where do i miss something?

UPD I **can't** change the way handler was attached!

Comment: "when I try to fire it programmatically" - what do you mean?

Comment: Good question.  But, why are you mixing your event bindings, btw?  Or is it different script files using different ways of binding events?

Comment: @Webars programmatically = `$(element).trigger('event')`

Comment: So attach second function in the same way as the first one.

Comment: @David Hoerster, I actially have binded event and want to trigger it from chrome extension. Just added the second one to stress out the problem. May be I should not.

Comment: @Webars I can't, i can't, i can't, i can't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native way to trigger events is to call [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent). Unfortunately, this method does not appear anywhere in [jQuery's source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). So I am guessing you have to either create the event objects yourselves and dispatch them manually.

Here's a longer version with a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/ebzeh/).

```
$('button').click(function() {
        var myEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
        myEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keyup', true, true, null, false, 
                                false, false, false, 76, 0);
        $('input').each(function() {
            this.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
        });
    });
```

Or you could look at jQuery [simulate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/simulate/jquery.simulate.js?r=6163) which makes it slightly easier. Here's a shorter version with another working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/fCWaz/).

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('input').simulate('keyup');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clear now.
It's not necessary, but may be I could somehow extend jQuery trigger functionality that it would do those fake `KeyboardEvent`s inside?

Comment: I haven't looked at the source of trigger, but replacing it with your own code is fairly `easy`. However, then you would have to deal with problems of normalizing a DOM event to a jQuery event to make sure all other event handling works normally, setting the right properties on that event object, and dealing with cross-browser issues. The solution is not as simple as creating a wrapper, which dispatches the DOM events directly and then calls jQuery's implementation as then the same event will be triggered twice in that case - once for all events on the element, and once for jQuery bound events